# Should I use vnd.youtube:videoID?

Tags: android, android-intent

While playing around with the emulator, I noticed that when trying to view a YouTube video the browser gives an error saying it can not load the page at `vnd.youtube:ngc978y6rCU?some=parameters`. I don't have an Android device, but by this I can suppose that launching a `VIEW` intent with the data URI set to `vnd.youtube:VIDEO_ID` would launch the default YouTube application and watch that video.

Now, my application has to be able to display YouTube videos. Right now I have a custom-made YouTube activity which does just that, but I'm thinking of:

- Removing my custom activity and just launching a `VIEW` intent with a `vnd.youtube:VIDEO_ID` Uri, or
- Testing whether that `Intent` [is available](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/sending.html#Verify) and using it, or, if it's not available, using my custom activity.

Is this a good idea? Does this work at all (as I said I have no Android device, I'll just be borrowing one from a friend to test my final application)? Which way should I go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Test if an `VIEW` intent with data set to `http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xxx` will work. It is possible for Android applications to hook like this. This would provide a better experience if the phone is somehow missing the Youtube app (and you don't want to rely in your custom player).

Comment: That would launch the Browser first and then the YouTube app, if there is a YouTube app. Going back from the YouTube app to my app would be a pain for the user.

Comment: That would only launch the browser first if the browser has been selected over YouTube as the default app for that URL pattern. You can set the package on the Intent you are using to "com.google.android.youtube" to circumvent that as well.  
  
E.g.:  
    private const val YOUTUBE_APP_PACKAGE = "com.google.android.youtube" 
    val openYouTubeIntent = Intent(ACTION_VIEW) 
    openYouTubeIntent.data = Uri.parse(link) 
    openYouTubeIntent.`package` = YOUTUBE_APP_PACKAGE

Answer (score 2):

It's up to you.  You could use the Youtube Intent but since those details have never been released it could be changed and break your code.

Comment: That is more or less obvious. But, if I go for option 2, it shouldn't break my code, right?